# Remove AD Security Group from Users O365 OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, azure-powershell

we have a problem that all users OneDrives have added a couple of AD security groups. I have spoken to MS and they cannot locate where these groups have come from and think it must be via powershell.

The group is a security group from an on-prem domain controller that is synced to Azure AD. Does anyone know how I can remove it from all users one drives? Is there a way I can see all the groups? Also, Im a global admin but powershell is complaining I dont have permissions if I do the following

```
PS C:\Users\me\blah> Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://xyz-my.sharepoint.com/personal/users_site.com

Get-SPOSiteGroup : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://tbwgroupplc-my.sharepoint.com/personal ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SPOSiteGroup], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetSPOSiteGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the command, you need to be the site collection administrator. Global admins doesn't have auto access to all sites and each user's OneDrive, but they can give themselves access to any site or OneDrive.

So you need to run the below command to give yourself access to OneDrive first.

```
Set-SPOUser -Site https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/users_site.com -LoginName admin@contoso.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
```

Besides, the AD groups are seen as normal users in SharePoint site, so I think you should use `get-spouser` instead of `get-spositegroup`